# How to get Co-ordinates on onmouseup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I have built a javascript application for dragging and dropping divs from one place to another in the same page. I have made the dragging part. I have the co-ordinates of the div(s) where I must drop the div but I am stuck at the part where I should introduce conditions for matching the divs at target zone. Basically the divs can be dropped above any of the divs but they must drop exactly above the target div if on onmouseup event I am anywhere close to that target div. I am thinking of assigning the top and left attribute of my dragged(onmousdown) div to the target div but I may be wrong.. Please guide my through this part.
Here is the part where I need help:

```
function mouseUp(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var mousePos = mouseCoords(e);
    var itemPosition = getPosition(id);
    //console.log("This is at: "+itemPosition);
    //console.log(mousePos);
    console.log(getPosition(id));
    for(var i=0;i<destination.length;i++)
    {
        var curTarget = destination[i];
        var targPos = getPosition(curTarget);
        var targWidth = parseInt(curTarget.offsetWidth); 
        var targHeight = parseInt(curTarget.offsetHeight);
        var temp = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);

    }


    id = null;
}
```

Here is the link to my code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyhmLpsb/) The javascript part must be written inside of html to make it work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question title is misleading, what you really seem to be having trouble with is finding the coordinates of the target divs. You're grabbing mouse coordinates just fine using `clientX` and `clientY` though you likely want to be using the `pageX` and `pageY` coordinates as they are relative to the rendered page and not the viewport (ie. window the user is looking at). 0,0 using the client coordinates will change as the user scrolls whereas the page coordinates will reference a particular spot on the webpage.

As for finding your drop divs you can use the method `getClientBoundingRect` on the element and use the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties on the returned object to determine if the `pageX` and `pageY` coordinates of the mouse are inside (or close to inside) the element.

Maybe there's a better way, but this is how I would do it.

```
function mouseUp(e){
  var targets = document.getElementsByClassName("drop_here");
  for(var i=0;i<targets.length;i++){
      var bounds = targets[i].getClientBoundingRect();
      var lenience  = 5;
      if(e.pageX < bounds.right + lenience &&
         e.pageX > bounds.left - lenience &&
         e.pageY < bounds.top - lenience &&
         e.pageY > bounds.bottom + lenience){
        //do my work here   
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you update my jsfiddle link with what you are saying? Thanks for the answer btw..

Comment: I'll write an example in my answer, not going to write it into your code for you though.

Comment: sure.. an example would be sufficient :)

Comment: Added an example, the `lenience` variable is added so that you can add a bit of extra space since you stated you might want to support the user being "close enough" when dropping. Just be careful that it doesn't count as being dropped in 2 boxes at once. Unless you're okay with that.

Comment: Thanks again..By 'do my work' you mean changing of dragged div's top and left attribute to that of target ?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't sure what you wanted to do once it was dropped in the target. If you want it to move over top of it then yeah, that's what you'd do. You could even just add the draggable element as a child of the target, rather than moving it with css.